# Read rtf File in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i have a rtf file, with 2 lines. I want to read it in objective c and every line should be represented in my textView1 and textView2 objects. Is that possible, can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString* readme = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ReadMe" ofType:@"rtf"];
[textView1 readRTFDFromFile:readme];
```

**EDIT**

```
NSString *strFromFile = [NSString  stringWithContentsOfFile:@"readMe" encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:null];
NSArray *array = [strFromFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
[textView1 setText: [array objectAtIndex:0]];
[textView2 setText: [array objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Comment: That won't work on iOS.

Comment: Yes. Thats cool, but i want firstLine from rtf to be in textView1 and secondLine to be in textView2. Is that possible, sir?

Comment: see my edited post!
Hope that works!
Thanks!

Comment: I'll check soon. I hope it will work. Thanks a lot

Comment: No. It doesn't work, I think is not possible to read rtf files on iPhone